# Wierd Problem in linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a very weird(and probably stupid too) but I can't understand it. Consider the equation $6x + 10y = 200$ and $x + y = 20$. Now if we add these two equations, then by logic, $x+y$ should still be 20. Let's try to do that:

$Equation(1) + Equation(2) = 200 + 20$ which means that $7x + 11y = 220$

Now, let's take the x value to be 11.
So , $77 + 11y = 220$ and by solving this we get $y = 13$

Now, $x + y$  should be equal to 20, but $11 + 13 = 24$.

What problem am I doing here?

Comment: Well, you just set $x = 11$ without any reason. This is telling you that $x \ne 11$.

Comment: You just broke math.

Comment: Suppose $x+1=2$. I just set $x=11$ and get $12=2$. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You've just proved that there's no solution with $x=11$.

If you multiply both sides of $x+y=20$ by $10$, you get $10x + 10y = 200$. Together with $6x + 10y = 200$, you can conclude that $6x = 10x$, or $4x = 0$. So $x=0$. Proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem - you simply proved that there is no solution to this system of equations such that $ x = 11 $. You can't just ,,take $ x $ to be $11$''

Comment: So do we mean that the point (11,13) does not lie on this line?

Comment: Which line do you mean?

Comment: Of course $(11,13)$ lies on the line $7x + 11y = 220$. But the problem is to find the intersection of the two lines given by the original equations.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the system

$$6x+10y=200,\\x+y=20,\\x=11.$$ which is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a single solution to those equations as one could take $x+y=20$ and make a substitution into the second one:

$6x+10y=200\iff 6x+6y+4y=200 \iff 120+4y=200 \iff 4y=80 \iff y=20$ Thus, the solution is $x=0$,$y=20$ for both equations to be true.

When you take $x=11$ there may not be a value that holds for both equations.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one point that lies on both of the lines

$$
6x+10y=200 
\\
x+y=20
$$

That point is $(0,20)$, not $(11,13)$